# Howto lookup repeating rows in Column A and place the corresponding data from column B into transposed columns C & D?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to look up a repeating label **Name** and get all instances of that value in a different column?  So I have really long list of data that's grouped by rows instead of in colums (Columns A & B below) and I want to make a list of data like columns C & D.  I was able to get rid of most of the unneeded data by using filters and copying to a different sheet.

```
A    B       C      D
Name Vic     Vic    Meat
Date None    Bee    Low
Peer Help
Look Meat

Name Bee
Date Today
Peer Great
Look Low
```

I am trying to generate columns C & D looking up the values in A & B.  I tried to transpose the data into columns but since it's repeating in chunks I wasn't able to.

Comment: do all the data blocks have the same rows?

Answer (score 0):

Could be achieved with two PivotTables, both with `A` as FILTERS and `B` as ROWS, one filtered for `Name` and the other for `Look`.